# Usage of 'comprise' in a linguistic manner

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, literature

> The small man did not hesitate. "I'm stealing.", he declared in a soft, simple voice, that did not **comprise** even the faintest tremble.

Is this a good, nice-sounding way of describing a way of speaking, where one sounds confident in his statement, or is the term 'comprise' not to be used in a linguistic manner (in works of literature)?

Comment: Source? Please acknowledge the original author. Provide broader context if possible.

Comment: What exactly bugs you about *comprise* here? Can you elaborate? I guess you are a non-native speaker of the English language.

Comment: @Kris that's correct, I am a non-native speaker trying to get an idea of how I can alter the appearance of a sentence by using different terms. I am a native german speaker and 'zeigte keine Spur von Unsicherheit' = 'showed no trace of insecureness' would sound a lot less formal than ,for example 'Da war nicht ein Hauch von Unsicherheit in seinem Sprechen'. I am trying to learn to express things in different ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"comprise" is not the best word choice here.  "Betray" is a possibility. Or even the very simple "have"; and  "did not comprise" could also be replaced with "lacked".

*Comprise* is not incorrect by any means.  But I think it stands out in a way you might not want. It is unlike the other words in the sentence. But perhaps it reveals the character of the narrator?  We'd need to see more, to be surer.

P.S. We also say that a tone of voice can "contain" a slight tremble. But I think *contain* would be better suited to a story where there *was* a slight tremble, and the thief was trying to have mastery over his nervousness. *Did not contain* isn't on the money.

Comment: Thank you! 'Betray' seems to fit my needs, as I want do emphasize that his speaking did not show any signs of insecureness. Using 'lacked' to paraphrase the meaning is a neat idea, too!

Comment: *Comprise* is most certainly incorrect, unless the writer wishes to imply that the voice and the tremble were the same.

Comment: I would love to hear what character you imagine when 'comprise' is being used. Maybe this will provide me with a better idea of when it should be used. p.s 'bespeak' comes to my mind,too, even though i know it's rather archaic

Comment: @TimLymington: *comprise* can also mean "contain"; it does not mean only "consist of".

Comment: @Sprottenwels: A narrator who used the word *comprise* to mean "contain" in that passage might be a snooty sort of Brit, member of an exclusive aristocratic club.

Comment: Somehow I fail to see anything odd with *comprise* here. Maybe if there was a list instead of a single *tremble,* that would have sounded acceptable to you?

Comment: @Kris: "comprise" meaning "to contain" is  a rarefied usage which seems to stand out from the diction of the rest of the sentence:  "small ... soft ... simple..".

Comment: @TimRomano & 1 other: That's a personal perspective. There's no such disqualification on *comprise*.

Comment: @Kris: What is the  referent of "That" in "That's a personal perspective"?  The statement about comprise=contains is rarefied, or that the word "comprise" is not in the same register as "small, soft, simple"? Or both?

Comment: @Kris: To say that the usage of "comprise" where it means "contains" is *rarefied*  (understood and used by only a small group of people) is a testable objective statement, accurate or inaccurate.  Tim Lymington's objection above serves to make my point. And to say that that usage of *comprise* is not in the same register as "small, soft, simple" goes to what is sometimes called "reading level".  Are you saying that all words and all of their meanings are equally known and employed across the entire population of native speakers?